# I/eatherforecast(19501): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver

Tags: flutter

When I run main.dart on my real phone code runs without any mistakes, I can see the string value exactly on my Location page but when I adjust my android emulator phone's location Turkey/İstanbul it stuckes on spinner (Loading page), Spinner keeps turning forever so Location page never open, by the way "I/eatherforecast(19501): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver" error written on console. I really wonder the reason of this tedious issue. Have a nice day..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:weatherforecast2/loadingpage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(),
      home: LoadingPage(),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:weatherforecast2/locationpage.dart';
import 'locationfinder.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'network.dart';

class LoadingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = "loadingpage";

  @override
  _LoadingPageState createState() => _LoadingPageState();
}
class _LoadingPageState extends State<LoadingPage> {
  Map<String,dynamic> currentLocationWeatherData;

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getDecodedCurrentLocationWeatherData();
  }

  void getDecodedCurrentLocationWeatherData()async{
    Position position=await LocationFinder().getCurrentLocation();
    currentLocationWeatherData = await NetworkHelper().getCurrentLocationWeather(position.latitude, 
    position.longitude);

    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return LocationPage(
        currentLocationWeatherData: currentLocationWeatherData,
      );
     }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child:SpinKitFadingCube(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 50,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
const String appid="57aad03f4e48ca815bb1184e74624f46";
const String openWeatherMapURL="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
class NetworkHelper{
  Future<dynamic>getCurrentLocationWeather(lat,lon)async{
    Response response=await get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
   lat=$lat&lon=$lon&appid=$appid");
    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    }
  }
}

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LocationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LocationPage({@required this.currentLocationWeatherData});
  final Map<String,dynamic> currentLocationWeatherData;
  static String id = "locationpage";

  @override
  _LocationPageState createState() => _LocationPageState();
}

class _LocationPageState extends State<LocationPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          widget.currentLocationWeatherData["weather"][0]["description"],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LocationFinder{
  Future<Position> getCurrentLocation()async{
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
    return position;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using an emulator. Have you tried wiping out the Emulator data? You can do that by going to Android Studio -> Tools -> AVD Manager -> Look for your emulator -> Select the little down caret at the right -> Wipe Data. WARNING! This will remove all the data from your emulator.

Comment: Also, you could try a new emulator with a recent API and an x86_64 architecture.